# Lua if statement error

Tags: if-statement, lua

I have this if statement and when I run it it reeturns an error : " ')' expected "

```
if (a=1 and b=4 and c=width/2) or (a=2 and b=1 and c=width/2) then
...
end
```

Am I doing something wrong here? or is it something wrong with lua?

Comment: I think your `=` need to be `==`. `=` sets a value while `==` compares values.

Comment: Not that I know much about Lua.. But should it not be == and not =?

Comment: If the below helped you solve your problem you should mark it as answer. Here's how you do it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to replace your current code with this:

```
if (a==1 and b==4 and c==width/2) or (a==2 and b==1 and c==width/2) then
...
end
```

`=` means assignment, whereas `==` checks for equality and it looks like you want to check for equality.

Comment: Oh haha i forgot that, Im so used to xcode which tells me if i make that mistake :P